# Walleye Boot.img for AOSP Build will not let me adb sideload

Tags: android, adb, android-source, rom

I am trying to make an AOSP build and push it onto a Pixel 2. I am using the Pixel Experience instructions and build here https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/walleye/build/. When I flash `fastboot flash boot boot.img` (The boot.img from my build) I then go into recovery mode and do a factory reset. I then try to update with adb and try to `adb sideload` my `<PixelExperience...>.zip` but I get an error saying that the computer cannot find any devices. I have made sure to allow connection to my computer for all times, I have also tried `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` to no avail. I thought it was a bad build so I built it again and I get the same error. Any help would be amazing! Thank you! (I have made sure in the Developer options that OEM is unlocked asw ell as Userdebug and that the USB connection is set to Transfer Files)

Comment: Maybe you need to enter recovery mode before using `adb sideload`. There is an article from TWRP team about `adb sideload`, https://twrp.me/faq/ADBSideload.html.

Comment: I have made an edit. I do go into recovery mode and do a wipe before trying to update using adb sideload. Right now I am not flashing a TWRP.img onto the device for recovery mode. Would you recommend I do that?

Comment: It's recommended from my opinion. It is TWRP for walleye link: https://dl.twrp.me/walleye/. You can follow instructions https://twrp.me/google/googlepixel2.html to flash and use TWRP for walleye.
When I use TWRP with my Pixel(sailfih), I should select specific TWRP version for it when I try to use it to flash custom ROM zip files. I don't know whether walleye needs this attention. If you have problems when using TWRP with walleye, you can try other versions.

Comment: Update: The twrp.img solved my issue it seems like. But not for other phones I am having similar problems with.